# Copy values from one sheet to another and remove duplicates?

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am trying to make one sheet's columns equal to another's without using copy and paste thinking that this will run faster. Then I am trying to remove the duplicate values in the new sheet's column(s). The code I have works, but since there is so much data it is slow!

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("COMP29")
ws.Columns(15).Copy Destination:=Sheets("TEMPLIST1").Columns(1)

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Remove Duplicates, Sort, and Name Temp Worksheet
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim LastRow As Long

'Name
ActiveSheet.Name = "TEMPLIST1"

'Remove Duplicates
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A1:B" & LastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 1), Header:=xlYes
End With
```

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this? With the unique list I am populating a ComboBox on DropButtonClick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the fastest way to perform the action, and it should be FAST - I can only think that you've got formulas in your list (or referencing your list) and they are slowing it down. Try turning off automatic calculations and see if that improves the situation (don't forget to turn them back on after your remove duplicates!)

Comment: I have the calculation to manual. I'll keep reviewing. I am not sure why it's slow. It takes roughly 5-15 seconds i would think. I would want it to be 1-2 second delay.

Comment: The only other suggestion I can think of is sheets("templist").range("a1:b" & lastrow).value=sheets("comp29").range("a1:b" & lastrow).value. It's not worth making an algorithm to go through and check for duplicates, and copying every new item, as Microsoft's built in functions are always going to be faster.

Comment: Thank you. I used the .value = .value and spend things up!